# Spring batch late binding for item reader and item writer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to implement late binding of item reader and item writer. The reader and writer should be dynamically configured.

**JobController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/job")
public class JobController {

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private Job customJob;

@RequestMapping(value = "/cust", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void runCustJob() {

    JobParametersBuilder jobBuilder = 
              new JobParametersBuilder();
    jobBuilder.addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis());
    jobBuilder.addString("reader", "fileToFileReader");
    jobBuilder.addString("writer", "fileToFileWriter"); 

    try {           
        jobLauncher.run(customJob, jobBuilder.toJobParameters());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

**JobConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private Environment env;    

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ac;


@Bean
@StepScope
public FileToFileReader fileToFileReader()//@Value("#    {jobParameters['filePath']}") String filePath
{
  //configure flatfileitemreader
    return reader;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public FileToFileWriter fileToFileWriter()
{
    //configure flatfileitemwriter
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Job customJob(@Value("#{jobParameters['reader']}") String reader,     @Value("#{jobParameters['writer']}") String writer)//@Value("#{jobParameters['reader']}") String reader, @Value("#{jobParameters['writer']}") String writer
{
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("customJob")
    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
    .flow(processFile1(reader, writer))
    .end()
    .build();
}

@Bean
public Step processFile1(String reader, String writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("processFile1").allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .<Person, Person> chunk(100)
            .reader((ItemReader<? extends Person>) ac.getBean(reader))
            .writer((ItemWriter<? super Person>) ac.getBean(writer))
            .build(); 
}
}
```

I want to set the bean name to jobParameters in JobController.java and access the bean by name in JobConfig.java. I tried @JobScope and @StepScope, but did not work or I might have used the scopes inappropriately.

Please tell me how to achieve the late binding.

Comment: I'm not confident with Javaconfig, but I suppose you have to use `fileToFileReader()` instead of `ac.getBean(reader)` (the same for writer)

Comment: I get your point, but here I want to set the reader and writers dynamically. I will have all the reader and writer beans written. 
I want to pass the bean names to the 'Step' configuration method, so that I can set those as reader and writer.

Comment: Do you have any flag to know when we should we reader/writer? If yes, we can have delegate to do it.

Comment: Yes, in controller I will have a flag or a value to decide which reader/writer to use. Currently I have hard coded as below,

jobBuilder.addString("reader", "fileToFileReader");    jobBuilder.addString("writer", "fileToFileWriter");